# global paperscript function, called by javascript win8 app

Tags: windows-store-apps, paperjs

I have an paperscript and I need to call a function in this paperscript from my Javascript to change some values.

I know that I can write it some way, that I dont need paperscript but only javascript. 
but I dont get it work.

Are there some other ways I can just export a paperscript function to javascript? or there are some other ways

I also saw something like this: but it also didnt work :-(

```
https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/17
```

--------- my current try to solve it --------

my javascript:

```
var paperscript = {};
```

my paperscript code till now:

```
this.someFunction = function(){ /*doSomething*/ };
//...
paper.install(window.paperscript);
```

the call outside of paperscript:

```
paperscript.someFunction();  //error, object doesnt have that function :-(
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code ([jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/igamec/1/edit)), javascript is used to call `someFunction` in the paperscript, turning the rectangle red:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/paperjs/paper.js/master/dist/paper.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var paperscript = {};
    window.onload = function(){
      paperscript.someFunction();
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="p">
    this.someFunction = function(){
      rect1.fillColor = new Color('red');
    };
    var rect1 = new Path.Rectangle({
        point: [0, 10],
        size: [100, 100],
        strokeColor: 'black'
        });
    paper.install(window.paperscript);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="p" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

My guess is that you have not been waiting until the paperscript loads before trying to access it with your javascript.  Paperscript does not (normally) load until after images have loaded; that's why this code uses `window.onload` to call the paperscript function.